# Android 8.0 EditText text color issues

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-8.0-oreo

Recently I have faced within an issue on EditText for Android 8.0 (HUAWEI P10 Plus):
[image]

for following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    EditText edittext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edittext.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edittext.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartway.testedittext"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

The issue is the following, by some reason when I set text color EditText does not changed color to Color.BLUE it does not changes:
[image]

But when I rotate a device text color is changed as expected:
[image]

When I start typing a text color changed again to default:
[image]

And when I rotate device again if changes to BLUE again:
[image]

The most interesting is when I type very long text at some point color of text is changed again to Color.BLUE:
[image]
[image]

And if I continue typing text its color resets again to default black:
[image]

Why text color is not changed when I set it to Color.BLUE and changed only after rotation of device ?
Have anyone faced with the same issue ? How to workaround with it ?

I have attached test project:
[TestEditText.zip](https://ufile.io/viekr)

Comment: Whats the question exactly?

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic Why text color is not changed when I set it to Color.BLUE and changed only after rotation of device. Seams like it is a bug is SDK I guess. But how to handle it

Comment: Ok i get it, yeah it seems like a bug, did you try to rebuild the project?

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic Yes, I have tired to rebuild a project and not once )) It did not help

Comment: can you setup a simple project so i can take a look, because i never seen something like this

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic I have added. See link in question to TestEditText.zip

Comment: I have an Oreo device and im not seeing this issue. Everything works as expected

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic You mean with my test project you see proper text color and on click color is changed properly ?

Comment: Yeah everything is perfect

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic What version of Android Studio you have ?

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic Seems like it is an issue on EMUI 8.0 of HUAWEI P10 Plus because in emulator I have perfect result